# Is page-break-before/inside/after still not supported in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit, printing-web-page

I don't understand why my tests for [CSS2 page-breaks](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page#page-breaks) don't reveal success -- MDN for [page-break-before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before), [page-break-inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside) and [page-break-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) indicate that `avoid` is supported since Safari (Webkit) 1.2 (125), yet in my tests, a sample XHTML 1.0 Strict document with the following CSS always has some headers separated from their corresponding tables, and also has some ≈5-lines-long table cells spanning between the pages, too.

```
h2 { page-break-after: avoid; }
table { page-break-before: avoid; }
td { page-break-inside: avoid; }
```

Why does this not appear to have any effect in OS X 10.8 Safari 6.0 and wkpdf?